# Is the row echelon form of a system of equations unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm talking about the row echelon form, not the reduced row echelon form. If it isn't can you give me some examples?

Comment: No, row echelon form is **not** unique. I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) might be helpful.

Comment: One important addition is that even though the REF is not unique, a lot of the most useful properties *are* unique, and will not change from REF to REF. For example, the rank, and the location of the pivot columns/free columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This matrix is already in row echelon form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but we can apply the row operation $R_1 \gets R_1 - R_2$ which gives another row echelon form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

[*Reduced* row echelon forms](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~oantolin/notes/row-echelon.html) are unique, however.

Answer (score 1):

No.  For example, take
$$A=\pmatrix{1&2\cr3&4\cr}\ .$$
Row reduction, first method:
$$A\sim\pmatrix{1&2\cr0&-2\cr}\ .$$
Second method:
$$A\sim\pmatrix{3&4\cr1&2\cr}\sim\pmatrix{3&4\cr0&\frac23\cr}\ .$$
Different echelon forms.

Answer (score -2):

Reduced row-echelon form of a matrix is unique, but row-echelon is not.
You may have different forms of the matrix and all are in row-echelon forms.